# Show that if $ \ C=\{c_n : n \in \omega \} \ $ is a countable subset of $ \ B \ $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ \ M=\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in \mathcal{N} \} \ $ such that each $ \ A_{\alpha} \ $ is countable and for $ \ \alpha <\beta \in \mathcal{N} \ $ , $ \ A_{\alpha}\ $ is a proper subset of $ \ A_{\beta} \ $. Let $ \ B=\bigcup A_{\alpha} \ $

**(a)** Determine the cardinality of $ \ B \ $.

**(b)** Show that if $ \ C=\{c_n : n \in \omega \} \ $ is a **countable subset of** $ \ B \ $ ,

**then** $ \ C \subset A_{\gamma} \ $ **for some** $ \ \gamma \in \mathcal{N} \ $.

**Answer:**

**(a)**

We know that countable union countable sets is again countable.

Thus $ \ \bigcup A_{\alpha}=B \ $ is countable.

**(b)**

Choose $ \ \gamma_n \ $ such that $ \ c_n \in A_{\gamma_n} \ $.

If possible let , the given statement is false.

Then we shall get a contradiction .

We assumed that,

$ C=\{c_n: n \in w \} \ $ is countable subset of $ \ B=\bigcup A_{\alpha} \ $ but $ \ C \nsubseteq A_{\gamma} \ $

**A contradiction need to produce right now**.

**But I am unable to do this.**

help me doing this

Comment: What is $N$, a set of ordinals, it seems. Not $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: And $w$ should be $\omega$?

Comment: yes $ N \ $ is given by $ \ \mathcal{N}_1\ $ , which may be set of ordinals . and $ \ w \ $ is actually $ \ \omega \ $

Comment: The union is not necessarily countable, but depends on the size of $\mathcal{N}$, in fact $|\mathcal{N}| \le |\bigcup \{A_\alpha: \alpha \in \mathcal{N}\} | \le \aleph_0 \cdot |\mathcal{N}|$, so assuming $\mathcal{N}$ is infinite, the total size is $|\mathcal{N}|$.

b) is only true when $\mathcal{N}$ has uncountable cofinality.

Comment: I need proof of (b). please do this clearly

Comment: We need extra info on $\mathcal{N}$. What is it? I can make a counterexample to b) otherwise.